# A fast, efficient way to calculate time differences between groups of rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have this table in a DataFrame, with the dates several cars have been refilled:

```
+-------+-------------+
| carId | refill_date |
+-------+-------------+
|     1 |  2020-03-01 |
+-------+-------------+
|     1 |  2020-03-12 |
+-------+-------------+
|     1 |  2020-04-04 |
+-------+-------------+
|     2 |  2020-03-07 |
+-------+-------------+
|     2 |  2020-03-26 |
+-------+-------------+
|     2 |  2020-04-01 |
+-------+-------------+
```

I would like to add a 3rd column, `time_elapsed`, with the duration between each refill.

```
+-------+-------------+--------------+
| carId | refill_date | time_elapsed |
+-------+-------------+--------------+
|     1 |  2020-03-01 |              |
+-------+-------------+--------------+
|     1 |  2020-03-12 |           11 |
+-------+-------------+--------------+
|     1 |  2020-04-04 |           23 |
+-------+-------------+--------------+
|     2 |  2020-03-07 |              |
+-------+-------------+--------------+
|     2 |  2020-03-26 |           19 |
+-------+-------------+--------------+
|     2 |  2020-04-01 |            6 |
+-------+-------------+--------------+
```

So here's what I do:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame

data = [
    {
        "carId": 1,
        "refill_date": "2020-3-1"
    },
    {
        "carId": 1,
        "refill_date": "2020-3-12"
    },
    {
        "carId": 1,
        "refill_date": "2020-4-4"
    },
    {
        "carId": 2,
        "refill_date": "2020-3-7"
    },
    {
        "carId": 2,
        "refill_date": "2020-3-26"
    },
    {
        "carId": 2,
        "refill_date": "2020-4-1"
    }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['refill_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['refill_date'])

for c in df['carId'].unique():
    df.loc[df['carId'] == c, 'time_elapsed'] = df.loc[df['carId'] == c,
                                                      'refill_date'].diff()
```

Which returns the expected results:

```
+---+-------+-------------+--------------+
|   | carId | refill_date | time_elapsed |
+---+-------+-------------+--------------+
| 0 |     1 |  2020-03-01 |          NaT |
+---+-------+-------------+--------------+
| 1 |     1 |  2020-03-12 |      11 days |
+---+-------+-------------+--------------+
| 2 |     1 |  2020-04-04 |      23 days |
+---+-------+-------------+--------------+
| 3 |     2 |  2020-03-07 |          NaT |
+---+-------+-------------+--------------+
| 4 |     2 |  2020-03-26 |      19 days |
+---+-------+-------------+--------------+
| 5 |     2 |  2020-04-01 |       6 days |
+---+-------+-------------+--------------+
```

So, everything looks OK, but here's the catch: in my real-life instance, my dataframe contains 3.5 million rows, and processing takes ages, even though it's a completely numerical, in-memory calculation with "only" 1711 groups to loop through.

Is there an alternative and faster way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using native pandas methods over a `df.groupby` should give significant performance boost over a "native python" loop:

```py
df['time_elapsed'] = df.groupby('carId')['refill_date'].diff()
```

Here's a small benchmark (on my laptop, YMMV...) using 100 cars with 31 days each,
showing an almost **10x** performance boost:

```py
import pandas as pd
import timeit

data = [{"carId": carId, "refill_date": "2020-3-"+str(day)} for carId in range(1,100) for day in range(1,32)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['refill_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['refill_date'])

def original_method():
    for c in df['carId'].unique():
        df.loc[df['carId'] == c, 'time_elapsed'] = df.loc[df['carId'] == c,
                                                          'refill_date'].diff()

def using_groupby():
    df['time_elapsed'] = df.groupby('carId')['refill_date'].diff()

time1 = timeit.timeit('original_method()', globals=globals(), number=100)
time2 = timeit.timeit('using_groupby()', globals=globals(), number=100)

print(time1)
print(time2)
print(time1/time2)
```

Output:

```
16.6183732
1.7910263000000022
9.278687420726307
```

Comment: you can also consider chaining `.dt.days` for a float column.

Comment: The problem with using `groupby` is that I'm not getting the expected output. I don't to do an aggregation, but to add a new column to the original ones. If I run `df.groupby('carId').diff().reset_index()`, I no longer have the `carId` to map the time difference to. Can I assume all rows are in the same order and I can just concaternate the tables side-by-side (`pd.concat([df, df.groupby('carId').diff()], axis=1)`)?

Comment: There seems to be indeed a match. I didn't think that `groupby` would do it, as I didn't want to agrgegate data, but I now learned that it does much more than aggregation! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `.groupby`:

```
df['time_elapsed'] = df.groupby('carId').diff()
```

output:

```
  refill_date
0         NaT
1     11 days
2     23 days
3         NaT
4     19 days
5      6 days
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the time_elapsed by using [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)  and subtracting from refill_date

```
(
    df.assign(
        refill_date=pd.to_datetime(df.refill_date),
        time_shift=lambda x: x.groupby("carId").refill_date.shift(),
        time_elapsed=lambda x: x.time_shift.sub(x.refill_date).abs(),
    )
)
```

The other answers using [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) are better, as that is more succinct, and I'd like to believe, faster.